# No mobile data on Nexus 4 Ubuntu Touch

Tags: networking, ubuntu-touch, nexus-4

I've installed 29/01/2014 Ubuntu Touch on my Nexus 4 (with .84 radio from Android 4.3). I can make/receive calls and connect to wifi but when I turn wifi off I see a 3G icon flash up two or three times in the top bar but then just the "no connection" icon.
There is definitely no data connection.
I understood that this should be working without any user intervention. My imei shows up in "about", mobile data is set to "on" and my carrier is correctly identified as "O2 UK".

Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

BTW I already tried creating a mobile data connection in desktop and then copying to "/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections" and bringing up with "nmcli con up id" etc but I got the error that the connection was not supported by oFono.

THANK YOU

Comment: Thanks for this post. I was having problems connecting my Nexus4 to Pennytel (in Australia). Just one point for clarification, on my version of Ubuntu Touch (14.04 (r229), the activate command is "activate-context". I am now able to surf with 3g data.

Comment: Having the same problem with a data SIM from Vodafone Italy, but not with H3G Italy. Does anyone knows the root cause of the problem? Why some operators require to configure the context manually?

Answer (score 1):

I got myself connected by using the following ofono script commands
in adb shell, first issue "cd /usr/share/ofono/scripts/"
"activate-connection"
"create-internet-context payandgo" (payandgo being my APN)

Still not sure why this worked as the default context did not contain any other details relating to O2 - for example, the password - but it did give me working 3G data.

For anyone else reading this, the command "set-context-property {context} {property} {value}" allows you to set any of the parameters contained in the given context (connection). For example, "set-context-property 0 Password payandgo" will set Password to "payandgo" in the default context. Also, the command "list-contexts" will show you the content of the context. If, while editing, it says the context is in use just issue "deactivate-context", make your changes, then "activate-context".
HTH

Answer (score 1):

Just providing more info on [fishears' answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/417622/208026):

1. Connect Nexus 4 to Ubuntu PC through usb
2. <kbd>Ctl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> (open terminal in Ubuntu PC)
3. Type `adb shell` (given you have added ppa:phablet-team/tools and installed the android-tools-adb package)
4. Type `cd /usr/share/ofono/scripts/`
5. Type `./deactivate-context`
6. Type `./create-internet-context [your APN]`**
7. Type `./set-context-property 0 Name [your APN name]`**
8. Type `./list-contexts` to see all parameters of the context you created in step 6. According to your APN you may need to set more parameters contained in the given context (e.g. password). Use `set-context-property {context} {property} {value}` to set all parameters necessary from your APN.
9. Type `./activate-context`

** Look them on Android under settings -> Mobile Networks -> Access Point Names (APN)

Comment: Can anyone confirm if the steps above helped resolve the mobile data issue? I have an E5 and my mobile data goes up and down something silly. I can be standing in one area and have no mobile data. I then turn flight mode on and off and then in the same area, I have full signal. I really want to try and resolve this issue as it is a real pain.