# Trouble changing the APN "MessageCenter" parameters for MMS in Ubuntu Touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch, wireless-access-point

I installed Ubuntu Touch on my Nexus 4 (14.10(r133) and I need to change the parameters in the APN contexts list for "MessageCenter" to show the correct MMS settings for my carrier.  I use a sub-carrier for T-Mobile here is the US and there is one bit of text that needs to change in order to use MMS.  I have no issue changing parameters for the APN "Name" or "AccessPointName" to show my carrier using `./set-context-property 0` command, only when trying to use "MessageCenter".

This is what I need to change (or edit):
MessageCenter = http://mms.msg.eng.t-mobile.com/mms/wapenc

This what I used (just need to add smpl to the address):
`./set-context-property 0`

MessageCenter http://smpl.mms.msg.eng.t-mobile.com/mms/wapenc

Here's the error:

```
Error setting context /ril_0/context1 property MessageCenter: org.ofono.Error.InvalidArguments: Invalid arguments in method call
```

So, not sure if this parameter can actually be changed or if it's a different command to just edit the parameter itself.  Hoping it's just something simple.  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Follow this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/413438/no-mobile-data-on-nexus-4-ubuntu-touch) it shows how to create context property. I hope this helps.