# Ubuntu Touch - Can't activate context

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

So I followed this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/413438/no-mobile-data-on-nexus-4-ubuntu-touch) to set up a 3G network on my nexus 4 which running Ubuntu Touch; however I cannot seemed to activate context.

This is a list of context:

```
[ /ril_0 ]
    [ /ril_0/context1 ]
        Type = internet
        Name = android
        Password = android
        AccessPointName = android
        Username = alex
        IPv6.Settings = { }
        Protocol = ip
        Settings = { }
        Active = 0
```

Does anyone knows what this error mean?

```
 ./activate-context
Error activating /ril_0/context1: org.ofono.Error.Failed: Operation failed
```

Sorry I'm not a developer and I'm quite new to Linux but I'm trying.

Comment: So I managed to fix this problem of mine by reverting from Ubuntu back to android and then reinstalling ubuntu again from devel channel. I thik the problem was the earlier insallation of ubuntu which didn't installed properly causing network problems and it was also a bit laggy and didn't have any apps available. If you hit the same problem just do what I did revert back to android and reinstall ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem on Nexus 7 LTE
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nuntium/+bug/1469496

but in my case reinstallation didn't help so far :'( and neither did this:
[No mobile data on Nexus 4 Ubuntu Touch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/413438/no-mobile-data-on-nexus-4-ubuntu-touch)